# How do I find out when the user is being followed by the map or not?

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I realise I can use a GoogleMap.OnMyLocationButtonClickListener to determine when the user has pressed the button to make the GoogleMap follow their location on screen, but is there a way I can receive an event for when the user is no longer following the device? For example, if the user has moved the map, which stops the map from locking to the user's location.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a OnCameraChangeListener, it will get called if the map is dragged.  In its onCameraChange compare the CameraPosition#target LatLng with MyLocation.

Here are the camera change and my location listeners in the same API:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.OnCameraChangeListener
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using a `View` overlapping `MapFragment` and overriding its `onTouchEvent`, checking `DOWN` event to stop following position. This is when user starts any interaction with map.

Comment: Sounds good for most use, might miss some cases like trackball / dpad / accessibility stuff.

Comment: @leorleor Good point, although GM Android API v2 doesn't support these either.